# Range of unsigned char in C language

Tags: c

As per my knowledge range of unsigned char in C is 0-255. but when I executed the below code its printing the 256 as output. How this is possible? I have got this code from "test your C skill" book which say char size is one byte.

```
main()
{
 unsigned char i = 0x80;
 printf("\n %d",i << 1);
}
```

Comment: The posted code will cause a compiler to raise a few warnings.   For instance, there are only 2 valid ways to write the main() function (plus one optional way).   1) int main( void )   2) int main( int argc, char * argv[])  and optionally: int main().    Notice that they ALL have a 'int' return type.   Most times, when returning from main() a 'valid' status indication is wanted.  so the last executable statement should be 'return( status );' where status is usually 0, unless an error occurred

Comment: 0x80 is NOT 255,  rather it is 128.   The unsigned char is 'promoted' to unsigned int.  so shifting 0x00000080 one bit left is 0x00000100.  Which when  printed results in 256.  Suggest reading up on parameter promotions in C

Comment: Note that `unsigned char` is not restricted to the range 0-255.

Comment: @user3629249 If you declare a function without specifying a return type, `int` is returned implicitly. Furthermore, `int main(void)` is not a portable declaration of the `main` function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Several things are happening.

First, the expression `i << 1` has type `int`, not `char`; the literal `1` has type `int`, so the type of `i` is "promoted" to `int`, and `0x100` is well within the range of a signed integer.

Secondly, the `%d` conversion specifier expects its corresponding argument to have type `int`.  So the argument is being interpreted as an integer.

If you want to print the numeric value of a signed `char`, use the conversion specifier `%hhd`.  If you want to print the numeric value of an unsigned `char`, use `%hhu`.

Comment: I guess %d promoting the unsigned char to int. I have tried printf("\n %hhu",i << 1) and its printing 0.

Comment: @Amandeepsinghsaini.gmail.com: No: the format string does not influence argument conversion (even if, the result of the shift with an 8 bit `unsigned char` would be `0`). for `hhu`: read [here](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.6.1p7): it takes an 'int' and interprest as `char`.

Comment: Unlike most binary operators, the bitwise shift operators do not perform the "usual arithmetic conversions" on their operands. The operands undergo integer promotion, but are not forced to be the same width or signedness. The type of the shift expression is the promoted type of its left-hand operand, which in this case wil be int, regardless of the type of its righthand operand. Sections 6.5.7 and 6.3.1.1/2

Comment: For bitshift operators, the result type is that of the left operand only. The right is just promoted if smaller (lower rank) than `int`.

Comment: Note that interpreting an `unsigned` type as `signed` is implementtion defined if the actual valus is larger than the max. representable value of the `signed` type.

Comment: False! Both `%hhd` and `%hhu` have the same effect in `printf` as the argument is promoted to `int` as per K&R argument promotion rules before `printf` sees it anyway.

Comment: @FUZxxl: `char` is always promoted to int if passed as argument, that has nothing to do with `printf`, etc.. However `%hhd` and `%hhu` interpret that argument differently. So: it is you, who is wrong here! As much as `%hd` and `%hu` differ. Or do you want to imply that there is no difference at all, as all take an `int` argument? Note that we are talking about _standard C_, not K&R C! The current (and only valid) standard is C11.

Comment: @Olaf `char` is only promoted to `int` in a function call when the function argument has type `int`, the function is not prototyped (i.e. declared with a K&R-style declaration) or when the argument is part of the variable arguments (e.g. all but the first argument to `printf`). The latter two rules are called K&R argument promotion rules.

Comment: @Olaf See ISO 9899:2011§6.5.2.2/6.

Comment: @FUZxxl: you should have read the next paragraph (7), too. For variadic arguments, _default argument promotions_ (there is no phrase "K&R argument promotions" in the standard) are performed as much as for non-prototype functions, too. (sounds logical, as the compiler cannot deduce their types). Note this is a reason, e.g. `"%c"` takes an `int`, not a `char` argument. That is a compatibility relic to K&R (but still not called like that). However, I should have mentioned about variadic argument lists.

Comment: @Olaf `char` is not promoted if it is passed as an argument to a function that expects an argument of type `char` which is one of the things I tried to outline.

Comment: I edited my last comment. But that was a minor flaw, as we actually **are**  talking about variadic arguments.

Answer (score 5):

Because the operands to `<<`<sup>*</sup> undergo *integer promotion*.  It's effectively equivalent to `(int)i << 1`.

---

<sub>* This is true for most operators in C.</sub>

Answer (score 2):

For arithmetical operations, `char` is promoted to `int` before the operation is performed. See [the standard](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.1.1) for details. Simplified: the "smaller" type is first brought to the "larger" type before the operation is performed. For the shift-operators, the resulting type is that of the left side operand, while for e.g. `+` and other "combining" operators it is the larger of both, but at least `int`. The latter means that `char` and `short` (and their `unsigned` counterparts are always promoted to `int` with the result being `int`, too. (simplified, for details please read the standard)

Note also that `%d` takes an `int` argument, not a `char`.

Additional notes:

- `unsigned char` has not necessarily the range `0..255`. Check `limits.h`, you will find `UCHAR_MAX` there.
- `char` and "byte" are synonymously used in the standard, but neither are necessarily 8 bits wide (just very likely for modern general purpose CPUs).

Answer (score 0):

As others have already explained, the statement "printf("\n %d",i << 1);" does integer promotion. So the one right shifting of integer value 128 results in 256. You could try the following code to print the maximum value of "unsigned char". The maximum value of "unsigned char" has all bits set. So a bitwise NOT operation using "~" should give you the maximum ASCII value of 255.

```
 int main()
 {
     unsigned char ch = ~0;
     printf("ch = %d\n", ch);
     return 0;
 }

Output:-
M-40UT:Desktop$ ./a.out 
ch = 255
```